# Geo localized database RTREE

Tags: mysql, spatial

I'm using MYSQL V5.6.24 GPL

I have a database with 200K rows and growing and I'm trying to get the nearest, based on points. I have all the database in InooDB, and to use Spatial data, I create one table with the Points with Mysiam.

everything works great, the problem is that when I sort based on ST_Distance, I'm not using any index, I create a SPATIAL index with the coordinates, and still using file_sort to sort. And Mysql doesn't allow me to use RTREE INDEX

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng) explains how to lay out your data to get very good speed for "finding the nearest 10 pizza parlors" from latitude/longitude.  It includes reference code.  It does not depend on SPATIAL or 5.7.  "200K and growing" is no problem.

It does depend on InnoDB (for clustered PRIMARY KEY), PARTITIONs (to get a pseudo-2D index), and a Stored Procedure (because of how messy the code is).  And it requires using a different datatype for latitude and longitude (because of PARTITION restrictions).

(Yeah, yeah, I know you would like me to spell it out here.  But it is too involved to fit here.)

Answer (score 2):

In order to get advantage of the SPATIAL index you have to filter results using a bounding box (or any other geometry type) with the functions `st_within()` or `st_contains()`. You have some examples here:

- [Query Optimization with MySQL 5.7 and MariaDB 10 - GIS Improvements](http://www.slideshare.net/jynus/query-optimization-with-mysql-57-and-mariadb-10-even-newer-tricks/77)
- [Using the new spatial functions in MySQL 5.6 for geo-enabled applications](http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/)
- [MySQL 5.7 and GIS, an Example](http://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-5-7-and-gis-an-example/)

Comment: Thanks @jynus, but is there a way to do faster queries, (maybe other DBMS) that can get me the points order by the nearest?

Comment: @EduardoIglesias You could try spinx geo distance function: http://sphinxsearch.com/blog/2013/07/02/geo-distances-with-sphinx/ but most RDBMs use similar indexes to speedup the WITHIN() function.